# Understanding a for loop in ADL

Tags: algorithm, for-loop

So I have been given this ADL code and asked to present a test table of results by going through the code with different number inputs. 
I understand most of it but I am struggling from the start of the `[` til the end of the `]`.

This is what I have got so far:
   For any negative value the code ends after the first if statement and does not display anything.
   For any 0 value the code ends after the second if statement.
  For any 1 value the code ends after the third if statement.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Consider the following algorithm written in ADL:

```
procedure unknown(IN number, OUT result, OUT status)

  declare i, number1, number2, sum

  status <-- true
  if number < 0 then [status <-- false]
  else
    if number = 0 then [result <-- 0]
    else
      if number = 1 then [result <-- 1]
      else
        **[number2 <-- 0
         number1 <-- 1
         for i <-- 2 to number do
           sum <-- number1 + number2
           number2 <-- number1
           number1 <-- sum
         end
         result <-- sum
        ]**
      endif
    endif
  endif
end // unknown
```

Using this algorithm, you are required to complete the following tasks:

i. Pretend to be a processor and execute the above algorithm by using the code walkthrough technique taught in  lectures. Devise your own test data for this purpose, and explain what this algorithm does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first three `if` statement, it does:

- if input < 0, then status = false;
- if input = 0, then output = 0;
- if input = 1, then output = 1;

When it comes to the final `else`, the `for i <--2 to number do` statement means to **repeat to do the body for (number-1) times** (`i` would be 2,3,4,...,number one by one, so you got (number-1) of `i`). The body is:

```
sum <-- number1 + number2
number2 <-- number1
number1 <-- sum
```

Let's see after each iteration (ada after i=2,3,4,...), what will these variables be:

```
i       number1     number2     sum
========================================
begin   1           0           N/A
2       1           1           1
3       2           1           2
4       3           2           3
5       5           3           5
6       8           5           8
7       13          8           13
8       21          13          21
```

You may see that the `sum` is a [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) that:

[image]

So let's complete the analysis by appending:

- if input = n (n>1), then output = Fibonacci number Fn.

Comment: I have just realised I should avoid comments like "thanks" but I don't know how to show my appreciation enough. I certainly would not of noticed it was a Fibonnacci sequence.

Comment: @JosephHistorg I'm glad to be of help. Have a nice day.